# Message templates token replacement: is it {if membership_end_date} or {if {membership_end_date}}?

Tags: tokens, message-templates, smarty

And  similarly, would it be   `{membership_end_date|crmDate}` or  `{{membership_end_date}|crmDate}`?

Comment: If you go to Find Memberships and then from the results pick one and choose print/merge document, the tokens dropdown will be in membership context and give you a list. In the dropdown it's called expiration date.

Comment: @Demerit Right, there are some manually-added old tokens across templates we need to handle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be `{if '{membership.end_date}'}`
and

```
{membership.end_date|crmDate}
```

Comment: Note that `{if '{membership.end_date|boolean}'}`

is generally better - it is more reliable - although possibly not much difference for dates